# ECLiPSe Integration with VSCode

Tags: eclipse-clp

I have just spent a three hours trying to configure my working environment for VSCode and ECLiPSe (I am new to VSCode and rusty in ECLiPSe) in Windows.

So far

- I have created a task (and a keyboard shortcut) in VSCode to launch TkEclipse (the GUI)
- in TkECLiPSe Tools->TkECLiPSe Preference Editor I set the value of the Initial query called ... (which is the last option) to cd('//C/Users/[current working directory]'), compile([your file]).

but
I cannot resize the GUI window to something larger, so I have to do this manually

I know these are small annoyances, but since all new power users will encounter them, it could be useful to document a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of launching a fresh *tkeclipse* every time you changed your code, I'd suggest to run *vscode* and *tkeclipse* in parallel and leaving them both open.
You can then just click the **Make** button in *tkeclipse* to recompile after saving changes in *vscode*.

<del>There is currently no way of passing parameters into tkeclipse via the command line. But we could easily add a -f command line option (as the console *eclipse* has).</del> As of ECLiPSe 7.1, tkeclipse supports a `-f FILE` command line option to pass an initial source file, and a `-e QUERY` option to specify a query to be executed on startup.

As for the window size, the best solution would probably be to make *tkeclipse* remember its size on closure, and restore it on relaunch.  If you are just unhappy with the default and want to change it permanently, you could add a line like

```
wm geometry . 1200x900
```

at the top of your installation's `<ECLIPSEDIR>/lib_tcl/tkeclipse.tcl`